# Enclose code in braces and indent automatically in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, indentation, shortcut, curly-braces, keystroke

Is there any convenient way to do all these things at once in Xcode?
*Take a selected block of text and enclose it in a set of curly braces, each on their own line, with proper indentation like this:*

Before:

```
    idea.ponder()
    doSomething()
```

After selecting the 2 lines and hitting a shortcut:

```
    {
        idea.ponder()
        doSomething()
    }
```

… preferably with the cursor positioned just before the opening brace.

That way I could just, for instance, type `withAnimation` or `DispatchQueue.main.async` or `if !tooSleepy` and be on my way.

I find myself doing this sort of thing manually so often, and I've never seen a convenient Xcode shortcut. (Though there are shortcuts for indenting, for wrapping in braces without adding newlines, etc.) Am I missing something?

thanks!

Comment: I think this is what [Source Editor Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit/creating_a_source_editor_extension) is for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my machine, selecting the lines and typing a left curly brace does exactly what you just said. Example:

```
self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
self.contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
```

I select both lines (triple-click-and-drag) and hit `{` key, and I get

```
{
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

To get the cursor before the first curly brace, choose Editor > Selection > Balance Delimiters (you can give that a shortcut) and then left-arrow.

[image]

An alternative approach might be: select and cut the lines, use code completion to insert the desired construct, then paste the lines back in.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `?` **right after** you initiate a non-optional `UILabel()` by the way? Isn't it better to force unwrap (`!`) in such a situation?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini LOL not my code, I was answering a q. on SO, I was just editing the code of the OP of that q.

Comment: Ha—so easy! Thanks, @matt. My problem was that I wasn't including the indentation whitespace at the beginning of the selection when I hit {, so it didn't have that effect. Doubly happy because you taught me the triple-click-and-drag trick, which I never knew. Thanks!